# web.config connectionStrings on production server

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm attempting to deploy my first website containing a database. The test local version has the following connection strings

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;
                          AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;
                          User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="ConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AHData.mdf;IntegratedSecurity=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've setup the databases on the web hosting company server and they give me the following connections strings

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db479427514.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427514;User Id=dbo479427514;Password=****;

Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db479427535.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427535;User Id=dbo479427535;Password=****;
```

When I replace the local test connection strings with the new server ones using

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db479427535.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427535;User Id=dbo479427535;Password=**I've used real password!**;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

   <add name="ConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db479427514.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427514;User Id=dbo479427514;Password=**I've used real password!**;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get the following error

> Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> [ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.]
>
> [ArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
>   Parameter name: connectionString]

Can anyone advise what is wrong here?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77ff9db1-c69d-4a14-b606-d208832b8756/keyword-not-supported-provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the 'provider' section of the connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db479427535.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427535;    User Id=dbo479427535;Password=**I've used real password!**;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

becomes

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=db479427535.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427535;User Id=dbo479427535;Password=**I've used real password!**;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Because the provider name is specified in it's own name-value pair (`providerName=`) I doubt it would be needed in the connection string. Give it a crack and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your Connecting sting to:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="
    Data Source=db479427535.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427535;
    User Id=dbo479427535;Password=**I've used real password!**;"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="
    Data Source=db479427514.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db479427514;
    User Id=dbo479427514;Password=**I've used real password!**;"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

This is because we dont have provider object in connection string, so remove that and specify the provider name under "providerName" section of connection string to: System.Data.OleDb